# Problem with migration from Apache to IIS

Tags: 6, migrations, iis

[I run a website with Drupal in Linux/Cpanel/Apache/MySql](http://devel.drupaleasy.ir/amad-bsco) and it worked perfect.
I want to put [this site in Windows/plesk/IIS/MySql](http://www.amad-bsco.com). I backed up and restore database in the new host and copied Drupal files.

My website run in new host with some problem.

1. I can't see administrative page; this page is white.
2. My links don't work with clean URLs and I should add (?q=) to links.
3. My images with ImageCache are not shown. The URLs for images are not correct and have a space.

Answer (score 6):

You need to translate the Apache server's rewrite rules into their IIS equivalents, in the root web.config.

For reference, see what is reported in the [Windows Download Instructions](http://drupal.org/node/557898).

> **IIS7: Create/modify web.config file.** Drupal distributions come with .htaccess files for *nix use; IIS7 users should convert this file to a web.config file for their site. If you have used the IIS Manager to create a new site, a basic web.config file will exist in your site's root directory.

Comment: My Drupal version is 6.I download D7.7 and copied web.config file to root,but have problem so![see](http://www.amad-bsco.com)
help me... please

Comment: are you using iis7

Comment: I am using IIS 6

Answer (score 0):

1. It can be solved by cleaning all cache tables using something like phpMyAdmin.
2. See the other answer; just use the web.config file that comes with Drupal.
3. It will be solved if point #2 is solved, and the right permissions are set.

Answer (score 0):

Running D6 on an IIS machine is a little more difficult. You require a IIS module that allows for rewrite rules, there a quite a few, some free others are a paid solution. There will be quite a few quirks to work out. But that should get you started.